# Nesting Navigation Tabs

Tags: routes

In my custom module, I'm defining a menu_item with the type *MENU_NORMAL_ITEM*. In the default bartik theme, this adds a new navigation tab (next to the *Home* tab). This is great; however, I need nested tabs as well! Something like the following:

```
<li>Home (default tab on Bartik)</li>
<li>Menu Navigation Item added via custom module</li>
    <ol>
        <li>Nested Friend</li>
    </ol>
</li>
```

With a structure similar to this, my frontend guys can theme around this and make a dropdown out of it. I've tried this:

```
$items['custom tab'] = array...
$items['custom tab/sub-item'] = array...
```

But there's no luck, and it's not even rendered when I clear my caches and do na inspect element, so I know it's not hidden or anything. I think I'm attempting to define a parent/child relationship purely through PHP. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the type for submenu.

```
 $items['custom tab'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,,
);
 $items['custom tab/sub-item'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
);
```

Comment: Here's a link to what I see -- https://www.dropbox.com/s/cto8ib7skv6mvo3/Screenshot%202014-09-18%2010.54.29.png?dl=0


Here's what my code looks like--[https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpqaxi2d4xhhq9h/Screenshot%202014-09-18%2010.55.42.png?dl=0]

I'm not entirely sure what I'm expecting here because I know Bartik doesn't support dropdown menus out of the box. However the HTML is generated, I'd like it if my theme devs have an HTML structure that can be turned into a dropdown via CSS and JS. Err..does that make sense?

Comment: It is better to use https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish module for submenu.